# When updating data from websockets, how can I update individual child components without socketing to every child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

So I have a frontend that needs to be updated with certain data every 2-ish seconds. Currently I have it set up so that my frontend sends a `init` message over a websocket to my backend. Upon receiving this, the backend starts an interval to send the data every 2 seconds until it receives a `clear` message to clear the interval.

I see two options:

1. I can set up a socket at the layer where each slice of data is needed and apply it to state, so that when the polled data changes, so does state, and therefore the component.
2. I can set up a socket with all the data at the top layer and pass the data down through props to my child components.

Option 1 would mean I'm setting up and handling a lot of sockets, which is undesirable.

Option 2 is my preferred option, but I'm a little uneducated on how to pull this off while keeping this app performing well. I don't want to update the entire page every time one piece of data changes if everything is held in state at the top layer. Can I set this up so that if `data x` changes but `data y` doesn't, then only the component that has `data x` passed to its props gets changed?

Comment: Use [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and do not make all child component props dependant on one parent. With the Redux store, you can actually have centralized storage for props but update specific components when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3. You can set up a socket with all the data in a context provider at the top layer and subscribe to each slice of data from context consumers. To do this you'll need to learn about [contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). However, I recommend checking out Redux because [`useSelector()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) will allow you to easily segment your data into slices without impacting performance of your application.

Comment: Ok this looks promising. Contexts is something I've neglected a bit so far in my React education. Can you tell me if I would still be able to update my individual components on specific updates with this technique, as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, contexts avoid the anti-pattern of what you described in option 2, which is called "props drilling". You'll be able to provide the realtime events from your socket contained in the state of a context provider at the top of your app, to several deeply nested components within your app that may or may not care about different slices of data, regardless of whether or not those slices overlap.